# Where can I watch the Chuunibyou specials?

Tags: love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions

I’m seeing all this stuff about Chuunibyou and it’s specials however I’ve only seen the 2 seasons on crunchy roll and can’t find the rest of its content anywhere someone

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you can watch them legally on the internet since most specials that I know of from other anime are usually included in BD/DVD releases or bundled together with manga or light novel volumes.

From [MAL](https://myanimelist.net), here are where you can find *Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai!* specials:

1. **Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai!: Kirameki no... Slapstick Noel** -
   Episode 13, included in the final volume of the BD/DVD.
2. **Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai!: Lite** - Short episodes aired on KyoAni's official YouTube channel. Also included in *Love, Chunibyo & Other Delusions! DVD/Blu-ray Complete Collections* as a 22 min Extra entitled Chuni-Shorts.
3. **Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai!: Depth of Field - Ai to Nikushimi Gekijou** - Specials bundled with the 1st season's BD/DVD volumes.
4. **Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai! Ren Specials** - Specials included in BD and DVD of *Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai! Ren*.
5. **Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai! Ren Lite** - Short episodes aired on KyoAni's official YouTube channel

Looks like you need to buy the BD's/DVD's to watch these specials. Regarding those specials aired in KyoAni's YouTube channel, I tried finding them but I think they were only a one-time thing, probably aired on specific dates before in their YouTube channel.

Comment: And of course these are likely to not have any English subtitles.